# what does curl stuck at "Trying <ip address>" indicate?

Tags: networking, azure, https, curl

We have a fleet of beaglebone boards running Debian 7.9 that communicate with our server (an Azure App Service) over https. From at least one of these boards, most requests to the server timeout. When I run `curl <my_api_url> -v`, it simply hangs at "Trying":

```
* About to connect() to <my_api_url> port 443 (#0)
*   Trying <ip address>...
```

Notes:

- On other boards, `curl <my_api_url>` works just fine
- On this board, I can ping and curl other sites just fine. The speedtest gave 9.74 Mbits/s up 0.85 Mbits/s down.
- On this board, requests to our server seem to work occasionally (for a short window every 10-15 minutes or so), but otherwise timeout.
- I also tried just using the server ip address directly. `curl https://<ip>/api/v2` connects just fine from other boards, but from this board, it gets stuck at `Trying` just the same. So it doesn't seem to be a DNS issue.
- The request above is made over https, so it's using port 443. But other https requests from this board work fine, so it doesn't seem like a port availability issue. Anyways, the same request to our server over http (port 80) also gets stuck at `Trying` on this board.

What could be the cause, and what other tools can I use to investigate what is going on with this particular board and url? How can I determine in the first place if it is an issue with the client/board, the Azure server, or somewhere in between?

Comment: Does your server have multiple A and AAAA records? Looks like happy eyeballs trying multiple IPs. Have you checked dns and port availability? Netcat?

Comment: As far as I can tell there is only the one A record. All of the requests try the same IP address (the requests from other boards that succeed and requests that are timing out from this board). Traceroute to that IP address from this board seems fine.

Comment: netcat seems to be working okay, although I don't exactly what I should be checking. I couldn't simply use `nc -l 2345` and `nc localhost 2345`. Instead I used `nc -l -p 2345 127.0.0.1` and `nc 127.0.0.1 2345`, but that worked. Same for port 433.

Comment: You would be doing `nc ip 443` it sounds like a firewall issue dropping your connection.

Comment: Okay, `nc ip 80 -v` from a working board shows an open connection to the server, but the same from the nonworking board shows no output. And is it clear from this that it is a firewall issue on the client network, or could it be the server side? If it's a firewall issue on the client network, it seems to be *only* blocking the server ip address (or a range?). If it's a firewall issue on the server side, it seems to be *only* blocking requests from this board. Would either of those make very much sense?

Comment: Run a TCP dump, keep testing until you replicate, then pull down the pcap file and inspect the communication. Also, as others mentioned, perhaps there are multiple A records and one or more of the servers is timing out part of the time.

Comment: Thanks, I've been able to replicate 100% of the time today: success on other boards (or from my desktop) and failure from this board. It is the only board on its network at the moment, so possibly other boards would fail from that network, I can't test that easily. We have a pretty basic plan, which seems to be limited to only one instance of the App on Azure, which suggests to me a single server. Are there other ways to confirm that?

Comment: Packet drop seems to occure. Curls default timeout values are very high, try --connect-timeout 10 to limit connection timeout to 10 seconds. Default is 300 seconds before curl gives up. https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT.html